# How to create a WordPress gallery with pagination

Tags: pagination

How would I create a gallery like this - https://www.sumcoco.com/2019/02/08/30-dutch-braid-tutorial-for-2019-latest-season/27/

The pagination also changes the url for each image...

I know the above site uses WP-PageNavi

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Portfolio Designer WordPress plugin](https://wpportfoliodesigner.com/). This plugin helps to create a gallery or portfolio with attractive layouts. 
This plugin has 3 types of pagination.

- Standard Pagination
- Load More &
- Autoload.

It helps you to create a gallery on your website with pagination. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Hi Mary - thanks for that...but I dont think thats quite what Im looking for...I dont want the images to link to anything - what I need is a single image at a time on the page and as you scroll through them the url changes...I mean its pretty much 100% like this: https://www.sumcoco.com/2019/02/08/30-dutch-braid-tutorial-for-2019-latest-season/27/